# Issue with string replace

Tags: php

I did a php code

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
                                アブソリュート・デュオ>

)
```

It return me this..

I did the following to try replace the empty space.

```
$m_name = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $m_name);
$m_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($m_name));
if($m_name!="")
{array_push($m_array,$m_name);}

print_r($m_array);
```

But the empty space seems to still persist. wonder what could it be and how do I replace the white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping the order of these two functions:

```
$m_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($m_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `trim()` function first to remove white spaces around the string. Later do other stuffs to string

```
<?php
//same string asigned to $i
$i=' 
                                    アブソリュート・デュオ>';




//your code     
echo '<pre>';
print_r($i);
echo '</pre>';

//use trim() to remove white space  around the string                               
$i=trim($i);
// now print the result white space removed in $i
echo '<pre>';
print_r($i);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```